# paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException client.connect format

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, paramiko

I am trying to log in to a remote machine (EC2). But it keeps saying there is an SSHException and the key is Invalid.

```
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Invalid key (class: RSAKey, data type: oQIBAAKCAQEApkTX3as35p1TF9W..............
```

This is my code:

```
import paramiko

amznKey = "MIIEoQIBAAKCAQEApkTX3as35p1TF9W............."
key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=bytes(amznKey, 'utf-8'))
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.get_host_keys().add('ubuntu@ec2-3-123-12-80.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com', 
'ssh-rsa', key)
client.connect('ubuntu@ec2-2-134-99-80.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com', username='', password='')
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls')
for line in stdout:
    print('... ' + line.strip('\n'))
client.close()
```

And also, is there a better way to SSH to EC2 with python?

Comment: What is the end-result you are actually trying to achieve. _Why_ do you wish to connect to an EC2 instance via Python? SSH is normally for interactive sessions. If you explain more about what you are trying to accomplish, we might be able to recommend a better approach (eg using Systems Manager Run Command).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thanks! I resolved it, it looks like I made a simple error. I was trying to SSH to the remote machine so I could initiate a process to keep running in the background for a project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, I found out the answer thanks to a friend. Although it is a simple mistake I made I am going to mention it here as it's difficult to trace back the error.

It's because I have given the `host=` as `user@host`. Here is a working code if anyone needs it. And the username is usually the OS you are using with AWS. e.g. `ubuntu` for Ubuntu.

```
import paramiko


hostname = "ec2-3-123-12-80.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com"  # Remote machine's public DNS
username = "ubuntu"  # Username for SSH                                     
pass_key = "amzonLinux16.pem"  # Your Private Key for AWS EC2

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)
client.connect(hostname, username=username, key_filename=pass_key)
for command in 'echo "Hello, world!"', 'cat ~/test', 'uptime', 'ifconfig':
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    stdin.close()
    print(stdout.read().decode('utf-8'))
    stdout.close()
    stderr.close()
client.close()
```

Comment: You aren't building an RSAKey from a string manually anymore, so this doesn't solve the issue that I and other people coming from google are looking for